# CSV -> JSON -> PostgreSQL "Token invalid"

Tags: python, json, postgresql, pandas

I have a CSV file containing 1 column ("json_doc") with many rows of JSON data. I want to collect this json data and upload it to a Postgres database. The rows are in the format:

```
{"id": "0436d9b9305d", "base": {"ateco": [{"code": "46.11.03", "rootCode": "G", "description": "Agenti e rappresentanti di animali vivi"}], "founded": "1972-07-10", "legalName": "COBEM - S.R.L.", "legalForms": [{"name": "Società Di Capitale", "level": 1}, {"name": "Società A Responsabilità Limitata", "level": 2}]}, "name": "COBEM - S.R.L.", "people": {"items": [{"name": "45808b0b5b5affa871c8e91169bb10c6930fac56", "givenName": "64e4393f477394f11f6477ca76395ed469548865", "familyName": "68ee44f14dc54d664dffe63195d42a14988b69bb"}]}, "country": "it", "locations": {}}
```

There are millions of rows, and not all of the formatting is consistent i.e. some nested dictionaries are structurally different to others.

I've taken 5 of these rows, and applied the following Python:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('samplecol.csv')
df = df.to_json('data.json')
```

I then use https://jsonlint.com to check the JSON and all is good.

I have a JSON file, data.json, and a PostgreSQL database, and want to get data.json into Postgres.

I run the following to create a table :

```
SN_ITA_test=# CREATE TABLE jsons(ID serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, info jsonb NOT NULL);
```

When I try to upload the file to Postgres using :

```
SN_ITA_test=# \copy jsons (info) FROM 'data.json';
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "id" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"json_doc":{"0":"{"id...
COPY jsons, line 1, column info: "{"json_doc":{"0":"{"id": "0436d9b9305d", "base": {"ateco": [{"code": "46.11.03", "rootCode": "G", "d..."
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?